# Combinatorial proof for this stirling number of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Anyone know how to do a combinatorial proof for this stirling number of second kind $S(m,m-1) = \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ for all integers $m\geq$ 1. Thanks in advance.
$S(m,n)$ denote that the set of all partitions of $\{1,...,m\}$ into exactly $n$ non-empty subsets.

Answer (score 2):

You have $m$ elements and $m-1$ boxes. This means that exactly one box has to contain exactly $2$ elements. Can you take it from here?

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it, can you explain more explicitly ?

Comment: How many ways are there to make a box with $2$ elements?

Comment: I see, thank you.